# Is there any way to view Nuget package sources available for visual studio directly from command line

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, command-line, nuget

How do I view Nuget package sources in visual studio through command line, WITHOUT going to package manager setting in visual studio? Also, dotnet cli also shows nuget package sources by running "dotnet nuget list source" command. Are these sources outputted by the dotnet cli the same nuget source in VS?

Comment: Are they the same?  WHy not try adding a source to VS and then seeing if the CLI outputs it?

Comment: I am slightly scared that I might mess up everything. Therefore, I asked this question.

Comment: You have all your code in git right?  If not do it.  The you can just revert any changes back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the nuget.exe here: https://www.nuget.org/downloads

Then run this command: `nuget.exe sources List`

Or you can directly check the `NuGet.Config` file in `%appdata%\NuGet`(the full path: C:\Users\ {username} \AppData\Roaming\NuGet)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't used the standalone nuget, however, I used the nuget that comes with dotnet core cli. So, upon modifying the nuget source tag in NuGet.config, those modifications were shown upon executing `dotnet nuget list source` command. Also, if I delete the NuGet.config file, the file gets regenerated after I executed any nuget command from the dotnet cli.

Comment: When I run the `dotnet nuget list source`, this link is shown, "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json". Also, in the NuGet.config the content is:
`<add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />`
where the value is value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json".

I just want to make whether the web link for the source is the official nuget source link or not.